# ¿Cómo hacer que un programa hecho en c quede instalado en Linux?

Tags: c, linux, shell

Tengo un SHELL que hecho a mano y ya lo compile con `gcc shiell.c -o shiell` y funciona bien.

Lo que quiero es poder instalarlo para que se pueda usar en linux en cualquier momento.

Answer (score 1):

Aquellos ejecutables que se encuentre en uno de los directorios de tu $PATH estarán disponibles para ser ejecutados. Con un simple:

```
$> echo $PATH
```

podrás ver los directorios dentro de tu path. Habitualmente para programas propios se suele utilizar /opt/tuprograma/bin/binario. Puedes añadir este nuevo directorio a tu path editando el archivo *~/.profile* y añadiendo la siguiente línea al final:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/tuprograma/bin
```

También puedes colocar el binario en cualquiera de los directorios por defecto en el *$PATH*, pero siempre es mejor no ensuciar el árbol de directorios del sistema y utilizar /opt en su lugar.

Comment: gracias me sirvió mucho  lo único que falto era poner export PATH de lo que me sugeriste pero con solo hecho de ver que era con el path ya pude hacerlo

Comment: @RodrigoRodríguez lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para ver cómo agradecer a Nache :)

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @Nache, usualmente no se recomienda ensuciar directorios de sistema como `/bin` o `/usr/bin`.

Si bien puedes extender el `PATH`, otra opción un poco mas simple es colocarlo en `/usr/local/bin`, que normalmente se usa para programas que instalas localmente. Dicho directorio suele ya estar en el PATH, asi que cualquier usuario va a poder ejecutar los binaries que coloques allí.